# Expressão regular para validar placa de carro

Tags: regex

Gostaria de uma empressão regular para validar placas de carro.

Hoje no Brasil temos 2 modelos: o antigo e mercosul.
 A diferença é que no 5º caractere, no mercosul é apenas texto enquanto que na antiga é apenas número, então para fazer uma regra que aceite ambos nesse campo deverá aceitar texto e número nesta 5ª casa.

Ex. da lógica:

**Algo do tipo:**

```
N - números
T - Texto
# - Ambos caracteres

TTTN#NN
```

Eu fiz assim:

```
^([^0-9][^0-9][^0-9][0-9][A-Za-z0-9][0-9][0-9])
```

Que funcionou [neste site](https://tools.lymas.com.br/regexp_br.php#).

A pergunta: está correto mesmo? Tem como encurtar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não está totalmente correto porque `[^0-9]` aceita **qualquer** caractere que não seja um dígito de 0 a 9. Ou seja, pode aceitar espaço, sinais de pontuação, letras acentuadas e de outros alfabetos, emojis, etc ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/8cpx8A/1)).

Se quer limitar a apenas letras de A a Z sem acento, use `[a-zA-Z]`, ou `[A-Z]` se quiser apenas letras maiúsculas.

Para as repetições, use [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) para indicar a quantidade exata:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9][A-Za-z0-9][0-9]{2}$
```

No caso, `{3}` significa "exatamente 3 ocorrências", então `[a-zA-Z]{3}` significa "exatamente 3 letras de A a Z, maiúsculas ou minúsculas". Portanto, `[0-9]{2}` significa "exatamente 2 dígitos de 0 a 9".

Também incluí o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$` que indica o final da string, assim eu garanto que não pode ter mais nenhum caractere depois (você usou o `^`, que indica o início da string, mas se não tiver o `$`, a regex aceita strings que possuem mais caracteres depois).

Também retirei os parênteses porque não parece ser necessário nesse caso.

---

Você também pode usar o atalho `\d` para os dígitos. Mas dependendo da linguagem/engine utilizada, ele também pode pegar outros caracteres, como por exemplo os [desta lista](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm). Como não foi especificada a linguagem/engine, fique com `[0-9]` mesmo, que com certeza só aceitará os dígitos de 0 a 9, independente da linguagem.

Comment: mais do que uma resposta uma aula, se pudesse dava +2